# Fetch data from Binance API to Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, json, api, get

I just started to work with API's and got a little bit confused of how can I transfer the data which I receive to a JavaScript array.
I have this code which receive the data from Binance API and show it in console.

```
var burl ='https://api.binance.com';

var query ='/api/v3/klines';

query += '?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=15m&limit=2';

var url = burl + query;

var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

ourRequest.open('GET',url,true);
ourRequest.onload = function(){
console.log(ourRequest.responseText);
}
ourRequest.send();
```

I also have a hard-scripted chart from FusionCharts Library.
The source code of a chart is here - [FusionChart Candlestick Chart](https://www.fusioncharts.com/charts/candlestick-charts/candlestick-chart-with-custom-trends?framework=javascript)

```
const dataSource = {
chart: {
caption: "Bitcoin Price",
subcaption: "Q4-2017",
numberprefix: "$",
pyaxisname: "Price (USD)",
showvolumechart: "1",
vnumberprefix: "$",
vyaxisname: "Volume traded",
exportenabled: 1,
theme: loadedTheme || ThemeAliases.light
 },
categories: [
{
  category: [
    {
      label: "Jan",
      x: "1"
    },
    {
      label: "Feb",
      x: "32"
    },
    {
      label: "Mar",
      x: "62"
    },
    {
      label:"Apr",
      x:"12"
    }
  ]
}
],
dataset: [
{
  data: [
    {
      tooltext:
        "<b>Oct 01, 2017</b><br>Open: <b>$openDataValue</b><br>Close: <b>$closeDataValue</b><br>High: <b>$highDataValue</b><br>Low: <b>$lowDataValue</b><br>Volume: <b>$volumeDataValue</b>",
      open: 4341.05,
      high: 4403.74,
      low: 4269.81,
      close: 4403.74,
      volume: 1208210000,
      x: 1
    },
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
var myChart = new FusionCharts({
type: "candlestick",
renderAt: "chart-container",
width: "75%",
height: "100%",
dataFormat: "json",
dataSource

}).render();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The result `ourRequest.responseText` is returned as a string, and not as an array. To fix it, simply use the `JSON.parse`method. You also store it in a variable, example :

```js
var burl ='https://api.binance.com';

var query ='/api/v3/klines';

query += '?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=15m&limit=2';

var url = burl + query;

var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

ourRequest.open('GET',url,true);
ourRequest.onload = function(){

  // Will convert the string to something Javascript can understand
  var result = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText); 

  // You can now use it as an array
  console.log(result);
}
ourRequest.send();
```

Does that answer the question?

Comment: I will definitely look documentation about it